# Detect two consecutive days and subset/filter a certain time period among two consecutive dates in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, time-series, subset

I have a data.frame of weather info in this link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/60p93cmhgdi93yd/weather%EF%BC%882%EF%BC%89.xlsx?dl=0

This weather info is recorded every 4-6 min (depending on days). I wanted to extract a certain period of time from the data.frame among the two consecutive days. For example, I would like to extract the time period from 9:45 am on 2018-4-9 through 9:45 am on 2018-4-10, and from 9:45 am on 2018-4-23 through 9:45 am on 2018-4-24, .....

I also created a fake data.frame as recommended, but my actual data.frame has 60+ groups of two consecutive days:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2018-4-9 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-4-10 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df2 <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2018-4-23 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-4-24 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df3 <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2018-5-7 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-5-8 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df <- rbind(df,df2,df3)
```

I have thought several ways to do this:

1. I can use the 'lubridate' package to transform time into the numeric form so I can define the duration of certain numbers to be extracted. But I also need to group every two consecutive dates together to calculate the duration. I had some code like this

```
daystart <- hm("0:0")

weather$date1 <- sort(as.Date(weather$Date))
a <- split(weather$date1,cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(weather$date1)>1)))
weather <- data.frame(weather,a)
#this does not work

weather <- weather %>%
  group_by(group #the grouped consecutive days) %>%
  mutate(dur = as.numeric(Time-daystart)) %>%
  filter(dur > xxx & dur < xxxx)
#I was thinking to do it this way
```

a grouped two consecutive days together but only return group ID once, thus it cannot be combined with the weather data.frame (I guess this is the problem). Also, I am not sure how to calculate the duration for every two consecutive days, but I think it could be done once I can group the consecutive days together.

2. I also thought about using "filter" and "ifelse" to extract the time

```
weather <- weather %>%
  filter(
    if(diff(Date) <= 1){
      Time <= trapstart
    }
    else{
    NULL
    }
  )
```

Something like this, but it does not work (of course).

What I really want to build the code is something like this (this is not actually the code)

```
weather <- weather %>%
  filter(
    if("these are two consecutive days"){
      "9:45 of the first day < Time <= 9:45 the second day"
    }
    else{
    NULL
    }
  )
```

The recording time of this data-frame is not consistent each day, thus the recording time may be different among days and the recorded data points are different among days.

Here is what I expect for the output (imagine I only have 5 records each day):

```
Date    Time    DateTime
4/9/2018    9:46    4/9/2018 9:46
4/9/2018    15:34   4/9/2018 15:34
4/9/2018    22:44   4/9/2018 22:44
4/10/2018   4:34    4/10/2018 4:34
4/10/2018   7:09    4/10/2018 7:09
4/10/2018   9:44    4/10/2018 9:44
4/23/2018   9:46    4/23/2018 9:46
4/23/2018   12:27   4/23/2018 12:27
4/23/2018   19:29   4/23/2018 19:29
4/24/2018   1:08    4/24/2018 1:08
4/24/2018   5:24    4/24/2018 5:24
4/24/2018   9:44    4/24/2018 9:44
5/7/2018    9:48    5/7/2018 9:48
5/7/2018    17:59   5/7/2018 17:59
5/8/2018    0:55    5/8/2018 0:55
5/8/2018    1:00    5/8/2018 1:00
5/8/2018    4:30    5/8/2018 4:30
5/8/2018    9:41    5/8/2018 9:41
```

I am not sure if I am stating my question in an understandable way since this logic thing is messing up my brain now... I would appreciate any suggestions and helps! Also, feel free to ask me to clarify my question if is it not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `dplyr::between` in the following way.

First, let's generate some sample data (always best to explicitly include data instead of providing a link).

```r
df <- data.frame(
    datetime = seq(
        as.POSIXct("2018-4-9 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-4-11 00:00"), by = "5 min"))
```

Then we can filter data between `"2018-4-9 9:45"` and `"2018-4-9 9:45"` using `dplyr::between`

```
library(dplyr)
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-4-9 9:45")
end <- as.POSIXct("2018-4-10 9:45")
df %>% filter(between(datetime, start, end))
```

PS. Perhaps a typo, but I think the library you are referring to in your post is called `lubridate`, not `lubricate`.

---

### Update

You can achieve filtering your source data by multiple `(start, end)` ranges using a non-equi join of your original data `df` and a dataframe that contains the different ranges.

Here's an example based on the sample data you give, and using `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join` to do the non-equi join:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
df_range <- data.frame(
    start = as.POSIXct(c("2018-4-9 9:45", "2018-4-23 9:45")),
    end = as.POSIXct(c("2018-4-10 9:45", "2018-4-24 9:45"))
)
df %>%
    fuzzy_inner_join(
        df_range, 
        by = c("datetime" = "start", "datetime" = "end"),
        match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
    select(-start, -end)
#              datetime
#1  2018-04-09 10:00:00
#2  2018-04-09 11:00:00
#3  2018-04-09 12:00:00
#4  2018-04-09 13:00:00
#5  2018-04-09 14:00:00
#6  2018-04-09 15:00:00
#7  2018-04-09 16:00:00
#8  2018-04-09 17:00:00
#9  2018-04-09 18:00:00
#10 2018-04-09 19:00:00
#11 2018-04-09 20:00:00
#12 2018-04-09 21:00:00
#13 2018-04-09 22:00:00
#14 2018-04-09 23:00:00
#15 2018-04-10 00:00:00
#16 2018-04-23 10:00:00
#17 2018-04-23 11:00:00
#18 2018-04-23 12:00:00
#19 2018-04-23 13:00:00
#20 2018-04-23 14:00:00
#21 2018-04-23 15:00:00
#22 2018-04-23 16:00:00
#23 2018-04-23 17:00:00
#24 2018-04-23 18:00:00
#25 2018-04-23 19:00:00
#26 2018-04-23 20:00:00
#27 2018-04-23 21:00:00
#28 2018-04-23 22:00:00
#29 2018-04-23 23:00:00
#30 2018-04-24 00:00:00
```

---

### Sample data

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
    datetime = seq(
        as.POSIXct("2018-4-9 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-4-10 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df2 <- data.frame(
    datetime = seq(
        as.POSIXct("2018-4-23 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-4-24 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df3 <- data.frame(
    datetime = seq(
        as.POSIXct("2018-5-7 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-5-8 00:00"), by = "60 min"))
df <- rbind(df1 , df2, df3)
```

Comment: Hi @Maurits Evers, Since I have about 100+ dates, is there a way to do it with all these days? And thank you for pointing out the typo. I have changed it.

Comment: @XM_Z *" Since I have about 100+ dates, is there a way to do it with all these days?"* I'm not sure what you mean. Can you edit your post to provide a more minimal example, perhaps based on the sample data that I give? Do you want to filter your source data for more than one `(start, end)` range? If so, please clarify on your expected output.

Comment: Hi @Maurits Evers, I edited my questions as recommended. Yes, I would like to filter my source data for more than one (start, end) range. I have 60+ groups of consecutive dates, and I would like to detect these consecutive dates, and filter a time period (9:45 am of the first day through 9:45 am the next day)among every group of these consecutive dates, for example, 2018-4-9 ~ 2018-4-10, 2018-4-23~2018-4-24, ...., 2020-6-5~2020-6-6.

Comment: Thanks for the update @XM_Z; I think what you're after is a non-equi join; I've made an edit to my post, please take a look. This should be straightforward to generalise for more ranges.

Comment: Thank you for the update, @Maurits Evers! I will spend some time working on the data to see if it works later today or tomorrow, and I will let you know.

Comment: Hi @Maurits Evers, it works! Luckily, I can read in a data.frame that have already had the start and end date times, so I don't have to define it for every two days. And the code you recommended worked well with my data set. Thank you!